# Any way to automate the Windows XBox Game DVR?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, automation, xbox-game-dvr

Is there a way to automate screen video recording using the XBox Game DVR (on Windows 10)?  I would like to set recording resolution and start/stop recording with something like Powershell.

Comment: Have you received your answer yet?